# Clear session on browser close-Native session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using native session library in my codeigniter  project.I want to destroy the session when browser close.is there any method for that?
In default session library `sess_expire_on_close` is there ,But in native session that setting is not there.I notice that native session is using **`PHPSESSID`** for the session.is any way to delete **`PHPSESSID`** from browser,when browser close?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

With this your session will remain active until the browser is closed